# Lightning standard flow control -set finish location

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I have two custom components and one standard flow component in my lightning page, I want to refresh the all components after completion of flow script

I'm having problem to find out the finish method in standard flow control, I know using visual force page I can achieve this, but I'm looking for if standard flow control can provide this functionality.

Please guide me on the Best way to handle this scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Application Events [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application.htm):

> Application events follow a traditional publish-subscribe model. An
>   application event is fired from an instance of a component. All
>   components that provide a handler for the event are notified.

You can use application events to communicate with other components that have the event handled on them.  In the Lightning Components Developer Guide they have a programming example on using application and component events.

Comment: Thanks  @JRiffe , Can you please share me any example on using standard Lightning flow how to communicate with other controller. I know we can handle the events between the vf page or controller but i'm not seeing any article / guide on how to communicate between standard lightning flow and controller.